# ASP.NET Core WebAPI ignores action attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-routing

I am struggling with new controller in my web api. I have two methods in it:

```
[Route("PositionSettingsForDay/{day}")]
[HttpGet("{day}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPositionSettingsForDay(int day) {...}

[Route("PositionSettingsForDay/{day}")]
[HttpDelete("{day}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeletePositionSettingsForDay(int day) {...}
```

When calling either one using Postman I am getting the following error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. The following
>   actions  matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:
>
> Backend.Controllers.PositionSettingsController.GetPositionSettingsForDay
>   (Backend)
>   Backend.Controllers.PositionSettingsController.DeletePositionSettingsForDay
>   (Backend)

In other controllers I have **Get** and **Delete** methods using same route without a problem.

Moreover, I discovered that even if I change routes to different ones my WebApi is still acting weird. 
When I send **Delete** request to my `GetPositionSettingsForDay` method instead of returning **404** it acts as if **Get** request was send.
[image: Result of unwanted delete]

Does anyone have any advice for me?

Comment: Try not passing parameter to HTTP attributes, e.g. `[HttpGet]`

Comment: You're using attribute routing in a wrong way. You should apply `[Route("PositionSettingsForDay")]` on your controller. Remove them in your actions and let only `HttpDelete` et `HttpGet`.

Comment: Such a simple thing... Thank you very much aaron!

Comment: Reference [Routing to Controller Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)